# Javascript Timer is not consistent

Tags: javascript

After the code runs a while, the countdown timer is not consistent and leaves gaps of multiple seconds. It still keeps counting down, but gets stuck at a specific count for a few seconds, then refreshes a few seconds later with an other number.

Here's the countdown function. Any ideas?

```
function countdownTimer(){

  //--Countdown til next TIME
  //--First, let's get today's date to do the calculation later
  var dM = new Date();
  var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
  var todayMonth = months[dM.getMonth()];

  var dD = new Date();
  var todayDate = dM.getDate();



  var dY = new Date();
  var todayYear = dM.getFullYear();



  //--Then let's set the countdown time to the next TIME

  if(window.nextTime == fajrTime){

    var tomorrow = todayDate + 1;
    var todayDate =   tomorrow + " " + todayMonth + "," + todayYear + " " + window.nextTime;

  }else{
    var todayDate =   todayDate + " " + todayMonth + "," + todayYear + " " + window.nextTime;

  }



  //-- Let's do the countdown calculation
  var deadline = new Date((todayDate)).getTime();
window.x = setTimeout(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var t = deadline - now;
  var hours = Math.floor((t%(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60)) +".";
  var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)) +".";
  var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML =hours;
  document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minutes;
  document.getElementById("second").innerHTML =seconds;
  if (t < 0) {
          clearInterval(window.x);
          document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML ='0';
          document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML ='0' ;
          document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = '0'; }
          update();
  }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: What is `update()` calling?

Comment: update() initialises a bunch of functions. Including:  clearInterval(window.x);
  countdownTimer();

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Then I imagine that there is some blocking code somewhere in your program that is causing a delay somewhere in between one interval ending and the next beginning. Try and use the setInterval method AND move any code that conceivably pause execution out of the interval's function.

Original:
Try refactoring your code to use setInterval(function, milliseconds) instead of setTimeout(function, milliseconds). In my experience its best to use built-in logic rather than writing your own.

Comment: I did try that, but had the exact same inconsistency after a while.